# Prism equivalent of UnityContainer.AddNewExtension

Tags: dependency-injection, prism, unity-container

We have a WPF application split into a few C sharp projects. Our Business layer needs to also register some Service objects with the Container. We believe the way to do this with Unity is

```
 Container.RegisterType<ISomeClass,SomeClass>();
```

in the Business layer C sharp library and then in the main UI application

```
 UnityContainer.AddNewExtension<T>();
```

The above is detailed here https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dependency-injection-using-unity-resolve-dependency-of-dependencies/

If we are using Prism what are the equivalent methods? Specifically we were
thinking of just using Unity (not Prism  )in the business library so that we can port it to Xamarin Mac and Linux. We would use Prism in the WPF UI application project only. Could this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically the answer from Haukinger is correct as you can always access the underlying container when/if you need to. In this case though, it probably is not the best approach here. Both the Bootstrapper and PrismApplication have a virtual method `CreateContainerExtension`. This is where Prism.Unity does:

```
// new UnityContainer() is created by default here...
return new UnityContainerExtension();
```

What I would suggest is that you configure the container upfront

```
protected override IContainerExtension CreateContainerExtension()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.AddExtension<SomeExtension>();
    return new UnityContainerExtension(container);
}
```

Comment: `IContainerExtension` might be a bit misleading, as it has nothing to do with `UnityContainerExtension` :-) That being said, `CreateContainerExtension` (or former `ConfigureContainer`) seems to be a good place, _if_ you can add the extension in the shell-project. If you're in a module, there's no way around `GetContainer`.

Comment: @Haukinger it's not misleading at all it's the Prism.Ioc.IContainerExtension. This is Prism's way of abstracting it's ability to work with different DI Containers such as Unity. What tech74 is looking to do is to add a Unity Extension to the Unity Container. The best way is to do just that, and then pass it into Prism's implementation of the IContainerExtension for Unity (UnityContainerExtension) so that Prism is able to do what it needs to do while you has the underlying container configured the way he needs.

Comment: "misleading" only in the context of this question, of course. Prism's `IContainerExtension` means "a wrapper around the container that enables it to be used though Prism's IOC-abstraction", while Unity's `UnityContainerExtension` means "a hook into the container that modifies its behavior". That's quite a  difference even though the names are nearly identical.

Comment: While you may be confused it’s not misleading at all even in the context of the question. I am aware of Unity Extensions. In the past Prism has used them.

Answer (score 1):

> If we are using Prism what are the equivalent methods?

There are some methods in `IContainerRegistry`, but their behavior isn't well documented (besides "they do what the container's method they're wrapping does") and they only cover the most common use cases.

Good news is, you can get the container back by using the `GetContainer` extension method for your container:

```
using Prism.Unity.Ioc;

containerRegistry.GetContainer().AddExtension<TheNeatExtension>();
```

Comment: Do you think there will be no issue between Vanilla Unity in the business library and Prism Unity in the UI application

Comment: There's no such thing as "Prism Unity", Prism just wraps a regular `UnityContainer`. You have to make sure that all your (registering and resolving) code uses the same instance of the container. If you use Prism's `IModule`, this is taken care of for you.